# Sum of polynomial ideals + intersection with vector spaces

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Consider ideals $I_1 = \left(x^{p}\right)$ and $I_2 = \left(y^{q}\right)$, both in $R = \mathbb{R}[x, y, z]$ with the natural grading,
$$
 R = \bigoplus_{k = 0,1,\dots} R_k\;.
$$
Let $R_{\leq k}$ denote the vector space $\sum_{j=0}^k R_k$. Are the following equal?

> **Question 1**:
>   $$
>   (I_1 + I_2) \cap R_{\leq k} = I_1 \cap R_{\leq k} + I_2 \cap R_{\leq k}
> $$

**Approach**

Right hand side is contained in the left hand side. For the other inclusion, $x^p$ and $y^q$ form a Grobner basis and so the following **can not** occur for polynomials $a_1, a_2 \in R$,
$$
 \deg(a_1x^p + a_2y^q) < \max(\deg(a_1x^p), \deg(a_2y^q)).
$$

> **Question 2**:
>   Will the statement be true if the union of the generators of $I_1$ and $I_2$ did not form a Grobner basis?

If anyone can correct/verify me reasoning. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This should be true for any homogeneous ideal $I$ in a graded ring $R$ ($\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-graded as in your example if you like). In particular, if your generators are homogeneous (as for $x^p$ and $y^q$), it will work.

Comment: Thanks. Should it work even when the generators do not form a Grobner basis? Ex. $I_1 = (x^2), I_2 = (xy)$?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because the generators of $I_1$ and $I_2$ are both homogeneous, hence the ideals themselves are homogeneous too. I don't know what a Gröbner basis is (sorry!), but I think it is not relevant for your question. In my opinion, you get a problem only for inhomogeneous generators like $x^2+y$.